Error with Python script when attempting to import CSV into SQL Server
What I am trying to do is to insert a CSV into an existing table in SQL Server without deleting any data in the table but I keep getting an error. Here is the full error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sampleUser\Desktop\Python Script\Food Services\Import to SSMS.py", line 55, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query, row['Visit Date'], row['Client ID'],
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 24 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision. (8023) (SQLExecDirectW)')

How do I address this error?
This is my full code that I have:
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

#File path to CSV
file_path = r'C:\Users\sampleUser\Downloads\someFile.csv'

#Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)


#Establish connection parameters
server = 'sampleServer'
database = 'sampleDatabase'
username = 'sampleUser'
password = 'PW1234!@#$'

#Connection string
conn_str = (
    f"DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};"
    f"SERVER={server};"
    f"DATABASE={database};"
    f"UID={username};"
    f"PWD={password}"
    )
 
#Connect to SQL Server
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Define table name
table_name = 'SomeTable'

#Insert DataFrame records one by one
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  query = f"""
INSERT INTO {table_name} (Visit Date, Guest ID, Last Name, First Name,
Date of Birth, Guest Age, Guest Gender, Guest Ethnicity,
Guest Ethnicity 2, Street, Line 2, City, County, State, Zip Code,
Housing Type, Latitude, Longitude, Household ID, Household Size, Primary Language,
Diet Restrictions, Taken At (UTC), Taken By, Company Visited,
Company Visited (Short Name), Plan Name, Individuals Served)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
"""
  
  cursor.execute(query, row['Visit Date'], row['Guest ID'],
                   row['Last Name'], row['First Name'],
                   row['Date of Birth'], row['Guest Age'],
                   row['Guest Gender'], row['Guest Ethnicity'],
                   row['Guest Ethnicity 2'], row['Street'],
                   row['Line 2'], row['City'], row['County'],
                   row['State'], row['Zip Code'], row['Housing Type'],
                   row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'], row['Household ID'],
                   row['Household Size'], row['Primary Language'],
                   row['Diet Restrictions'], row['Taken At (UTC)'],
                   row['Taken By'], row['Company Visited'],
                   row['Company Visited(Short Name)'], row['Plan Name'],
                   row['Individuals Served'])
  conn.commit()

cursor.close()
conn.close()

My ultimate end goal is to have this process automated once a month, I will run this using a batch file that will be executed by another program.  I have tried this "solution" but I cannot get this to work correctly, I have also tried to cut down the amount of parameters to 23 since the error happens at 24 (I think since that is what the error says) but the error persists. Any help will be appreciated.
# Convert specific column to float
columns_to_convert = ['Taken By']

for col in columns_to_convert:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')

df['Recorded By'].fillna(0, inplace=True)


You're not trying to insert into SSMS because SSMS is only a UI, you are tying to insert into SQL server.

The error tells you the precise cause? You are trying to insert into a float column, a string which cannot be converted into a float.

@DaleK you are correct, my mistake.

Looking at your data, the most likely values being mapped to float are latitude and longitude. Perhaps those values are represented as degrees/minutes/seconds instead of decimal degrees, or perhaps they are using a N/S/E/W prefix or suffix instead of signed numbers. Another possibility is that some may contain empty, null, NaN, or Infinity values that are not translating.

The answer is in the error message: at some point, you're trying to insert invalid data.
The quickest path to figure out what exactly is wrong with your data is to do some good old-fashion print debugging.
Insert the following snippet right before cursor.execute:
    print("Next insertion:")
    print(f"                  Visit Date: '{row['Visit Date']}'")
    print(f"                    Guest ID: '{row['Guest ID']}'")
    print(f"                   Last Name: '{row['Last Name']}'")
    print(f"                  First Name: '{row['First Name']}'")
    print(f"               Date of Birth: '{row['Date of Birth']}'")
    print(f"                   Guest Age: '{row['Guest Age']}'")
    print(f"                Guest Gender: '{row['Guest Gender']}'")
    print(f"             Guest Ethnicity: '{row['Guest Ethnicity']}'")
    print(f"           Guest Ethnicity 2: '{row['Guest Ethnicity 2']}'")
    print(f"                      Street: '{row['Street']}'")
    print(f"                      Line 2: '{row['Line 2']}'")
    print(f"                        City: '{row['City']}'")
    print(f"                      County: '{row['County']}'")
    print(f"                       State: '{row['State']}'")
    print(f"                    Zip Code: '{row['Zip Code']}'")
    print(f"                Housing Type: '{row['Housing Type']}'")
    print(f"                    Latitude: '{row['Latitude']}'")
    print(f"                   Longitude: '{row['Longitude']}'")
    print(f"                Household ID: '{row['Household ID']}'")
    print(f"              Household Size: '{row['Household Size']}'")
    print(f"            Primary Language: '{row['Primary Language']}'")
    print(f"           Diet Restrictions: '{row['Diet Restrictions']}'")
    print(f"              Taken At (UTC): '{row['Taken At (UTC)']}'")
    print(f"                    Taken By: '{row['Taken By']}'")
    print(f"             Company Visited: '{row['Company Visited']}'")
    print(f" Company Visited(Short Name): '{row['Company Visited(Short Name)']}'")
    print(f"                   Plan Name: '{row['Plan Name']}'")
    print(f"          Individuals Served: '{row['Individuals Served']}'")


When the program crashes, you can look at the log before the crash to see what's wrong with the data.

Thank you @Carson for the suggestion, I tried this and was getting a parameter 12 error.  I checked my file and noticed some discrepancies with dates. I updated file to with no discrepancies.  The error I am getting now is that I am getting the Guest ID on the Visit Date and Last Name of Client ID and so forth.  The record that gets printed with the suggestion is the first record and I have checked my file and it all seems correct.

I should also add that yesterday, these were aligned. The visit date was the visit date and the Guest ID was the Guest ID and so forth.  What was wrong with my file was the date format.
